# As an F1 student, what if I'm allowed to work in the US but won't need H1B sponsorship from employers?

Tags: usa, h1-visa

Im an engineering grad student under F1 status planning to graduate in 3 months. I haven't started my OPT process but plan to as soon as possible to obtain it by January. On job applications, the following two questions consistently appear:

1) If hired, can you furnish proof that you are eligible to work in the country where the job resides?

2) Will you now or in the future require sponsorship for an immigration-related employment benefit?

I would like to make sure I am not lying by answering 1) Yes and 2) No. The following will justify my answers:

1) Yes, I can furnish proof on the grounds that my OPT will be done by the time I graduate and I can thus provide this proof given a certain timeframe

2) No, I will not *require* sponsorship after my OPT expires. If the employer judges my work worth an H1B sponsorship, I will gladly accept it, however I do not now, or in the future require the employer to do anything on my behalf. Of course, I would *like* to have sponsorship but I do not *require* it.

Please let me know if I am answering these questions truthfully, bearing in mind that any other combination of answers automatically disqualifies my application on the grounds that I require sponsorship.

Comment: Is there any way I can improve or make this question easier to answer?

Comment: So you have no desire to stay in the US beyond the OPT period? If the company wants to try to arrange for an H-1B visa, they may have to do so very quickly, as applications have to be submitted on April 1st. I think you're better off immediately stating that you require sponsorship so that you end up at a company who understands what's involved.

Comment: I think you mistake the meaning of "require."  It can mean that something is a prerequisite, as in "because you want to drive across the border, you require an international insurance card."  It can also mean "demand," as you have used it in your discussion.  This second sense is quite rare in the US, and I suspect that they are asking more about conditions, prerequisites, and your intentions than about your relationship with your employer.  Since sponsorship is a prerequisite for working in the US, you should answer "yes" if you are applying for a job in the US.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are very standard questions in the job process. As a former F1 student myself, I would advice:

> 1) If hired, can you furnish proof that you are eligible to work in
>   the country where the job resides? -

Answer here would always be yes, cause without the eligibility proof there is no way you could start work anyways. The OPT serves as that proof.

> 2) Will you now or in the future require sponsorship for an
>   immigration-related employment benefit?

This one is a more trickier question. I believe the engineering OPT's now are about 36 months long. If the employer does like you and keeps you around for that long, they wont care whether you need sponsorship or no. They will find a way to keep you around. I know of great candidates who have missed out on opportunities because of the wrong response to this question. So leave it to you on this.